# Cannot access or use documents showing in mongo db terminal

Tags: mongodb, meteor, file-upload, meteor-packages

I created a collection called **Stampest** that stores a reference of an uploaded image and a title string, created by a user. Using the [ostrio:autoform package.](https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/autoform-files)This package creates a collection called **Images** where all the user uploaded images are stored and hense referenced to/from.

When I query mongo in my terminal using

```
db.stampest.find({})
```

I get the entries

[image]

Which shows that there are documents in the database, in the `Stampest` Collection. But the **PROBLEM** is that when I look at the collection in [Meteor Toys](https://github.com/MeteorToys/allthings) debug, it says its empty, and when I insert a document, in this case, the image and the title, the collection changes to 1 for a split second and geos back to 0. There are no error from the terminal or console

As a consequence, I cannot access these documents, what can I do?

This is the schema.js

```
Schemas = {};
Stampest  = new Meteor.Collection('stampest');

Stampest.allow({  
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return userId;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    return doc.userId === userId;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // can only remove your own documents
    return doc.userId === userId;
  }
});


Schemas.Stampest = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    max: 60
  },
  picture: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: 'fileUpload',
        collection: 'Images',
        // uploadTemplate: 'uploadField' // <- Optional
        // previewTemplate: 'uploadPreview' // <- Optional
      }
    }
  }
});

Stampest.attachSchema(Schemas.Stampest);
```

The `publish` is like this:

```
Meteor.publish('stampest', function () {
    return Stampest.find({author: this.userId}).fetch();
     console.log(Stampest.find());
});
```

The user inserts the `image` and the `title` like this:

```
<template name="createStamp">
    <div class="grid-block">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="upload-img">
                <a href="{{file.link}}">{{file.original.name}}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="new-stamp-container">
            {{> quickForm collection="Stampest" type="insert" id="insertStampForm" class="new-stamp-form"}}
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Check on the server using meteor mongo. If the record is there, it will be a problem with the way you are subscribing to the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you are returning an `Array` of db items and not a `Cursor` in your code.
If you take a look at https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html, you'll notice that regular `publications` return simple cursors or array of cursors but never your fetched data.

edit: also, the `console.log` in your publication will never be interpreted as it returns on the previous line.